# Modify one odeset parameter

Tags: matlab

I am using `ode15s` to solve a DAE problem. I give through `odeset` the Mass Matrix and some more info:

```
opts=odeset('Mass',M,'MassSingular','yes','MStateDependence','none');
```

I calculate also `Jpattern` from a previous run. To feed it to the function, I could write once again

```
opts=odeset('Mass',M,'MassSingular','yes','MStateDependence','none', 'JPattern',JPat);
```

**Is there a way to modify that single parameter and keep the rest of the structure?**

I tried

```
opts.JPattern = JPat;
```

But it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably do something like:

```
opts = odeset('Mass',M,'MassSingular','yes','MStateDependence','none');
opts = odeset(opts,'JPattern',JPat);
```

This is using the syntax (see the [documentation](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/odeset.html)):

> `options = odeset(oldopts,'name1',value1,...)` alters an existing
>   options structure `oldopts`. This sets options equal to the existing
>   structure `oldopts`, overwrites any values in `oldopts` that are
>   respecified using name/value pairs, and adds any new pairs to the
>   structure. The modified structure is returned as an output argument.